# Alternative to VGAM for Zero Truncated Negativ Binomial GLM in R

Tags: r, glm

Is there an alternative to the vgam Package to do a zero truncated negativ Binomial GLM in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is "no". `countreg` does zero-inflated and zero-truncated count distributions, but only Poisson and NB. `actuar` gives pdf, cdf, et cetera, but doesn't do regression.